# How to remove (f) bits from overflow byte in java

Tags: java, byte

How to get only b0 from byte value ffffffb0. I try (0xff & ffffffb0) but I still get the same results. Some solution.

Comment: 0xffffffb0 is hex value but how to get only b0 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mask *away* the higer-order bits, to force them to 0 and thus retain only the lower bits:

```
byte byteValue = 0xb0;
int byteValue = byte & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 1):

0xffffffb0 & 0x000000ff should work

Answer (score 0):

as a byte, 0xb0 is the same as 0xffffffb0. as an int, you can get it to be only 0xb0. (bit 7 is set, and Java has no concept of unsigned bytes)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println( Integer.toHexString(0xffffffb0 & 0x000000ff));
```